# Configurations for Solr NLP Integeration

Tags: solr, nlp, solr4, opennlp

I wish to use OpenNLP with SOLR . I have gone through the SOLR wiki and all the configurations given in it for the same. are there some special request handlers that need to be written? If no then what all configurations are there that can be made in schema and config file to get the SOLR NLP integration up and running.

I have used Open NLP individually for other text analysis processes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some instructions from Solr team on setting that up here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP.